# What happens if an app is running, and the provisionning profile is showing "Invalid Status"?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile

If an app is running, and the provisionning profile is showing "Invalid Status", do I have to regenerate it ? Will the app work without problems ? Do I have not to touch to de regeneration for the app working ?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Apple response about this.

[https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1878/_index.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1878/_index.htmlhttp://)

Comment: Many thanks, this is because I changed the push notification from Xcode and it has repercussion on the AppId. I didn't know that xcode was so powerful! I has to be careful in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You don't need to do anything, your app will be working fine for sure. But if you'll update your app version in future at that time you would require a provisioning profile then you can update your provision profile.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is running (truly running) it will continue to run.  The profile is checked when the app is launched.  However, this means if the app stops for any reason (killed by user, killed by OS for memory reasons or for being in background for long time, device restart, etc.), it will not launch unless you get an updated, valid provisioning profile onto the device.

There are multiple ways to do that, although the most common is to generate the new profile, and then rebuild and reinstall the app on the device.

Another method is to use MDM (mobile device management) to push the new, valid profile to the device.  If you do this, the existing app will launch just fine.

Finally, if you are using a wildcard app ID, you could install another app built with the new profile onto the device, and the original app will also run fine, even though it was installed with an old profile.